# NESTED IF's in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, nested-if

I am trying to write nested IFs in a pl/sql block. How do I arrange properly.

```
IF r1.CABLE_TYPE = "A" THEN
var_root = FC_CPSCBPR1.C_111_SCPSCBP
```

Logic I have to include now

```
If var_root is "TRUE" /*If the value is populated*/
  THEN 
       IF ...
            THEN
Elsif var_root is "FALSE" /*If the value is not found*/

      THEN
```

Comment: Not sure if this is part of your issue but you need single quotes for character literals, e.g. `'A'`, not `"A"`.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What trouble are you having with nested IF statements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#BABHIAAC) for nested IF statements.
You need an `END IF` to end each.

> ```
> DECLARE
>   PROCEDURE p (
>     sales  NUMBER,
>     quota  NUMBER,
>     emp_id NUMBER
>   )
>   IS
>     bonus  NUMBER := 0;
>   BEGIN
>     IF sales > (quota + 200) THEN
>       bonus := (sales - quota)/4;
>       IF whatever_else_you_like THEN
>         do_something_here;
>       END if;
>     ELSE
>       IF sales > quota THEN
>         bonus := 50;
>       ELSE
>         bonus := 0;
>       END IF;
>     END IF;     
>     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('bonus = ' || bonus);     
>     UPDATE employees
>     SET salary = salary + bonus 
>     WHERE employee_id = emp_id;
>   END p;
> BEGIN
>   p(10100, 10000, 120);
>   p(10500, 10000, 121);
>   p(9500, 10000, 122);
> END;
> /
> ```

You can also have as many [ELSIF](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#BABGEHAI) statements as you need.  eg.

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE p (sales NUMBER)
  IS
    bonus  NUMBER := 0;
  BEGIN 
    IF sales > 50000 THEN
      bonus := 1500;
    ELSIF sales > 35000 THEN
      bonus := 500;
    ELSE
      bonus := 100;
    END IF;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
      'Sales = ' || sales || ', bonus = ' || bonus || '.'
    );
  END p;
BEGIN
  p(55000);
  p(40000);
  p(30000);
END;
/
```

Comment: If I ask, I have to include one more IF statement when my bonus := (sales - quota)/4 is satisfied.

Comment: @SoomSatyam:  I added an IF statement in there - you should be able to nest these to arbitrary levels using the examples above.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this PL/SQL block structure example - you need to remember to end each one of `IF` statement as a closed block of code using `END IF` and semicolon `;`.

```
BEGIN

  IF 10 > 5 THEN

    IF 10 < 20 THEN
      dbms_output.put_line('statement 1 from nested if');
    ELSE
      dbms_output.put_line('statement 2 from nested if');
    END IF;

  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('statement not from nested if');
  END IF;

END;
```